# How is the suggested method used to estabish the stated result? In proof that a polynomial of degree n has at most n roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This question is based on the discussion in B4-1.2 of [Fundamentals of Mathematics, Volume 1](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/fundamentals-mathematics-volume-1) Edited by H. Behnke, F. Bachmann, K. Fladt, W. Süss and H. Kunle.

See the **bold text** for the part of the proof I am seeking help with.  My question is: how do I use the method suggested to obtain the needed result?

Technically this proof is applied to $\mathcal{R}$ which is an *arbitrary
commutative ring with unit element 1, and without null divisors*. And the expression

$$
f\left[x\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}
$$

is equivalent to an *entire rational function of one argument
in $\mathcal{R}.$* Here we have defined $0^{0}\equiv1$ to support
our notation. For the purpose of this question we can simply call
$f$ a *polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{R}.$*

Our objective is to prove the following theorem: If $f$ is expressible
in the form

$$
f\left[x\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}
$$

with $a_{n}\ne0,$ then $f$ has at most $n$ roots.

Proof: First we introduce the constant expressions

$$
\bar{a}_{k}=\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}a_{i}\alpha^{i-k-1},
$$

and the function

$$
f_{1}\left[x\right]\equiv\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k}\bar{a}_{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}x^{k}\bar{a}_{k}+a_{n}x^{n-1}.
$$

The right-most expression follows from $\bar{a}_{n-1}=a_{n},$ and
shows that $f_{1}$ has at most $n-1$ roots by the induction hypothesis.

Next we observe that for the real number constant $\alpha$ we have

$$
(x-\alpha)\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}x^{k}\alpha^{i-k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}x^{k+1}\alpha^{i-k-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}x^{k}\alpha^{i-k}
$$

$$
=\sum_{k=1}^{i}x^{k}\alpha^{i-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}x^{k}\alpha^{i-k}=x^{i}-\alpha^{i},
$$

and apply this result to obtain, for $n>0$

$$
f\left[x\right]-f\left[\alpha\right]=\left(x-\alpha\right)f_{1}\left[x\right].
$$

The case of $n=0$ is the constant function $f\left[x\right]=a_{0}x^{0},$
which is of the required form. If $\alpha$ is a root of $f,$ we have 
$$
f\left[x\right]-f\left[\alpha\right]=\left(x-\alpha\right)f_{1}\left[x\right]=0.
$$

If $x\ne\alpha,$ is a root of $f$ then $f_{1}\left[x\right]=0.$ It follows that $f$
has at most one more root than $f_{1}$ Since $f_{1}$ has at most $n-1$ roots this which completes the proof.

**The step I am not following is the establishment of $f\left[x\right]-f\left[\alpha\right]=\left(x-\alpha\right)f_{1}\left[x\right]$
using**

$$(x-\alpha)\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}x^{k}\alpha^{i-k-1}=x^{i}-\alpha^{i}.$$
I am able to establish the result using brute force as follows: Expand
$f_{1}$

$$
f_{1}\left[x\right]\equiv\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}a_{i}\alpha^{i-k-1}\right)x^{k}
$$

$$
=\left(a_{1}+a_{2}\alpha+a_{3}\alpha^{2}+a_{4}\alpha^{3}+\ldots+a_{n}\alpha^{n-1}\right)
$$

$$
+\left(a_{2}+a_{3}\alpha+a_{4}\alpha^{2}+a_{5}\alpha^{3}+\ldots+a_{n}\alpha^{n-2}\right)x
$$

$$
+\left(a_{3}+a_{4}\alpha+a_{5}\alpha^{2}+a_{6}\alpha^{3}+\ldots+a_{n}\alpha^{n-3}\right)x^{2}
$$

$$
+\dots+a_{n}x^{n-1}
$$

$$
=a_{1}+a_{2}(\alpha+x)+a_{3}\left(\alpha^{2}+\alpha x+x^{2}\right)
$$

$$
+a_{4}\left(\alpha^{3}+\alpha^{2}x+\alpha x^{2}+x^{3}\right)
$$

$$
+\ldots+a_{i}\left(\alpha^{i-1}+\alpha^{i-2}x+\ldots+\alpha x^{i-2}+x^{i-1}\right)
$$

$$
+\ldots+a_{i}\left(\alpha^{n-1}+\alpha^{n-2}x+\ldots+\alpha x^{n-2}+x^{n-1}\right).
$$

Multiplying by $\left(x-\alpha\right)$ and canceling like terms of opposite
sign produces the desired result

$$
\left(x-\alpha\right)f_{1}\left[x\right]=a_{1}\left(x-\alpha\right)+a_{2}(\alpha^{2}-x^{2})
$$

$$
+a_{3}\left(\alpha^{2}x+\alpha x^{2}+x^{3}-\alpha^{3}-\alpha^{2}x-\alpha x^{2}\right)
$$

$$
+\ldots+a_{i}\left(\alpha^{i-1}x+\alpha^{i-2}x^{2}+\ldots+\alpha^{2}x^{i-2}+\alpha x^{i-1}+x^{i}\right)
$$

$$
-a_{i}\left(\alpha^{i}+\alpha^{i-1}x+\alpha^{i-2}x^{2}+\ldots+\alpha^{2}x^{i-2}+\alpha x^{i-1}\right)
$$

$$
+\ldots+a_{n}\left(\alpha^{n-1}x+\alpha^{n-2}x^{2}+\ldots+\alpha^{2}x^{n-2}+\alpha x^{n-1}+x^{n}\right)
$$

$$
-a_{n}\left(\alpha^{n}+\alpha^{n-1}x+\alpha^{n-2}x^{2}+\ldots+\alpha^{2}x^{n-2}+\alpha x^{n-1}\right)
$$

$$
=f\left[x\right].
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
\begin{align*}
f[x]-f[\alpha]&=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i-\sum_{i=0}^na_i\alpha^i \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(x^i-\alpha^i) \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(x-\alpha)\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}x^{k}\alpha^{i-k-1} \\
&=(x-\alpha)\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}a_i\alpha^{i-k-1} x^{k}.
\end{align*}

Now we interchange the two sums to get 
\begin{align*}
f[x]-f[\alpha]&=(x-\alpha)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}a_i\alpha^{i-k-1}x^{k} \\
&=(x-\alpha)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\bar{a}_kx^k \\
&=(x-\alpha)f_1[x].
\end{align*}

Comment: I did find a way to do it by working backward from my brute-force method.  But I'm glad I asked.  Your way is better than mine.

Comment: I get $f_{1}\left[x\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}a_{i}x^{k}\alpha^{i-k-1}$ which is OK since the $a_0$ terms cancel in $f\left[x\right]-f\left[\alpha\right]$.  I will argue that your sum over $i$ in $(x-\alpha)\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}a_i\alpha^{i-k-1} x^{k}$ should begin at $i=1$ rather than $i=0$.  Do you agree?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference whether it starts at $i=0$ or $i=1$.  The $i=0$ term is $0$ anyways (there are no values of $k$ in the second summation if $i=0$).